# Storing data from a loop to an array

Tags: c++, loops

I'm new to c++ and my question is how do I store data from a loop cycle into a array, then print it?
Do I need to make another loop? if so how do I go about that? also if what I ask is possible, when every time I re-run the compiler will the array above get re-written or erased(hope it does)?

```
int getcard()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    int x;
    string mix[10];
    string h;

    do
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        {
            x = rand() % 18;
            h = master[x];

            cout << h << endl;
        }

        mix[10] = h;
    }
    while (false);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program is correct, except for many other things you do not ask.

Comment: There are many problems with your code not least of which is this `mix[10] = h;` which is writing to out of bounds array memory - indices are zero based in arrays

Comment: There is also nowhere you define "master", yet you use "h = master[x]".

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code creates a string array initializes it's elements to "string" and prints it out.

```
string array[10];


for (int i=0; i<10; i++){

    array[i] = "string";
}


for (int i=0; i<10; i++){

cout<<array[i] <<"       ";
}
```

You should try something in the line of this.

Comment: I think `vector<string>`is better in this scenario.

Comment: what is vector use for? or what does it do?

Comment: A vector is a variable sized array. It will get bigger if there is not enough space in it to store the item you want to add.